# PHP extension in capital letter downloads source code

Tags: php, security, amazon-ec2

I've been coding on my Local Machine recently using PHP 5.6.30 Built-in Server, just today I moved my local host files to my Amazon EC2 Windows Server with PHP 5.6.30 already installed, scanning my website with Acunetix, I saw a bug/vulnerability which downloaded my source code just by changing .php (Small Letter) to .PHP(Capital Letter).

The Question is This:

Is this Normal for the Built-in Server to download my source code to visitor or hacker when .php is capitalized or my bug, I always try to prevent myself from being hacked by all means...

E.g

I have index.php on my localhost served through PHP 5.6.30 Built-In Server.
When User visit same page (index.PHP), it download the code...

Comment: Somewhere in the request pipeline, when your server decides whether or not a file should be sent to the php engine, its doing a case-sensitive check for ".php". You're not running production with the built-in server are you?

Comment: I'm not running Production, just the default config for testing before uploading for production @castis

Comment: Can someone verify if it's me only?

Comment: The question is confusing? Is the problem on EC2 or the local machine?

Comment: @Barmar both have same problem...

Comment: I was able to solve it by replacing my PHP.ini to production

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to figure this out by replacing the server PHP.ini to the php.ini-production, moving the server to APACHE and it stopped acting that way.

@ castis hinted me on that word **"production"**.

Thanks.